# Как выравнивать текст по верхнему краю?

Tags: html

Как выравнивать текст по верхнему краю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/vertical-align

сам пользуюсь этим ресурсом постоянно - когда чего-нить забываю :)

Answer (score 2):

```
valign="top"
```

это для табличных ячеек например.

либо для все остальных в css или свойстве style можно написать

```
margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px
```

где margin -- это отступ снаружи, а padding -- внутри